# PGsql creating view

Tags: postgresql

i am new to pgsql 
i have a table1 containing many values , and i use a query by which i get 10 useful queries which are needed by me , i want to create a table 2 which will store these 10 useful queries or you can say a top view of table 1

But the table 1 keeps on changing after sometime so these 10 useful values are not fix, i want to create a view of table1 into table2 which gives me those useful queries whenever i access table2

Please suggest me a way using inherit or any other option by which i can create this view but only for Postgre SQL.

TABLE 1 - - - -> Runs a Query - - - - > TABLE 2

TABLE 1 Changes - - - -> Query Runs Again - - - - > TABLE 2 Latest

Comment: **Edit** your question and add the table definitions as `create table` statements. Add some sample data (as *formatted* text) and the expected output based on that sample data.

Comment: I *think* you are looking for a materialized view. I'm not really sure, it's very unclear.